# Java - Different result in console app according to program execution time

Tags: java, bubble-sort

I have implemented a simple bubble sort algorithm using Java (a console app). This is my ArrayBub class

```
public class ArrayBub {
private int[] _numbersArray;

// Constructor of class
public ArrayBub(int[] numbersArray) {
    _numbersArray = numbersArray;
}

public void BubbleSort() {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Bubble sort - sort " + _numbersArray.length + " numbers in array (random order)");
    System.out.println("Initial array: " + Arrays.toString(_numbersArray));
    int i, j, temp;
    int n = _numbersArray.length;

    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j < n - i; j++) {
            if (_numbersArray[j - 1] > _numbersArray[j]) {
                temp = _numbersArray[j - 1];
                _numbersArray[j - 1] = _numbersArray[j];
                _numbersArray[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Final array: " + Arrays.toString(_numbersArray));
    System.out.println("Number of iterations: " + (i + 1));
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long executionTime = endTime - startTime;
    System.out.println("Execution time (in milliseconds): " + executionTime);
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
}
```

Then i have a helper class where a create an array with random integers

```
public class ArrayGenerator {
public int[] GenerateRandomArray(int numberOfDigits) {
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int[] array = new int[numberOfDigits];
    long seed = System.nanoTime();
    int i;

    for (i = 1; i <= numberOfDigits; i++) {
        list.add(i);
    }

    Collections.shuffle(list, new Random(seed));

    for (i = 0; i <= list.size() - 1; i++) {
        array[i] = list.get(i).intValue();
    }

    return array;
}
```

And finally i call my ArrayBub class in the main method:

```
new ArrayBub(new ArrayGenerator().GenerateRandomArray(10)).BubbleSort();
```

**Here is the odd problem:** When i use a small array - lets say with 10 items - the result looks as expected

> Bubble sort - sort 10 numbers in array (random order)
>
> Initial array: [4, 5, 1, 9, 10, 6, 2, 8, 3, 7]
>
> Final array: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>
> Number of iterations: 10
>
> Execution time (in milliseconds): 1

But when i execute the exact same code for a very large number of integers (let's say 50000) the result is very weird. This is what the console shows

> Final array: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26.......]
>
> Number of iterations: 50000
>
> Execution time (in milliseconds): 4995
>
> Final array: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26.......]
>
> Initial array: [39500, 13400, 48276, 11997, 25616, .........]

**So why this is happening and the result gets messed up?**

Comment: Are you using Netbeans/eclipse console? Sometimes their integrated console does not respect the output order, but if you run it in the OS native terminal you should see the output in the correct order

Comment: @BackSlash yes i am using eclipse. I will try to run the code on terminal and let you know...

Comment: @BackSlash Even if i used console for the output the result is still strange. What i think is that the output is very big so eclipse and console cannot display it properly. What i did is that i wrote the output to a txt file and the code works fine for any number of digits even if it 50.000 digits. So maybe you should write your suggestion as response so i can accept it. Thanks!